# Segue in swift 2 issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, segue

I'm having a bit of a problem with a segue implementation in swift 2. So, I want to pass information from one ViewController to another. Here is what I do:

- I have OriginViewController and DestinationViewController.
- I override the prepareForSegue function as follows:

  ```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

      let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController

      destination.data = 155 

  }
  ```
- In DestinationViewController there is a variable **data** of Int? type without an initial value.
- I also created an Action Segue show, but it doesn't change the data variable in DestinationViewController after the button is pressed.

In output I have:

> SegueProject[12451:998869] Unknown class OriginViewController in Interface Builder file.

To be more specific, here is my project: https://yadi.sk/d/DVZVv04BkrjnH

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Let me explain my project a little bit. When the button on OriginViewController is pressed, a user goes to DestinationViewController, where he presses another button, which prints the data variable value to the console. The latter allows me to keep track of the data variable value.

Comment: I still see no question. Questions are usually the sentences with a question mark (`?`) instead of the period (`.`).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I haven't finished. As a matter of fact, the question is obvious - why it doesn't work? What have I done wrong?

Comment: How doesn't it work? When are you checking the `data` value in `DestinationViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your file named `OriginViewController`, but class is named `ViewController`. Rename your class to `OriginViewController` as set in your storyboard. and everything will work. In your case:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
```

change to

```
class OriginViewController: UIViewController
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, I overlooked that. But still, I have the same issue: the value doesn't change;

Comment: I downloaded your project fixed it and then cleaned. It works. Here's link to your project that I fixed: https://app.box.com/s/ybjwv6gu9kyab709lokfkxl5s3b4gjr5

Comment: Are you sure that you gave me the right link? I mean, firstly, the name of the class isn't changed. And secondly, it still doesn't work :) Proof: https://yadi.sk/i/tBhzcEgokrnEC

Comment: Interesting, it works :) Thank you very much, mate! But considering that after I renamed the class, the program didn't work and now your program works just fine, even despite the fact, that our programs are exactly the same. So, what's the deal?

Comment: You should clean your project, and recreate reference to class in storyboard(delete and create)

Comment: Clean? What does that mean?

Comment: Product-Clean in toolbar. It rebuilds target and cleans project caches.

Comment: Didn't know that. All right, again, thank you very much! Now everything works just fine :)